# Does Qt have general-purpose classes besides GUI-related classes?

Tags: qt

I have recently regained some interest in learning Qt, but have the following doubt:

Does Qt have enough classes that are not GUI-related?

For example, Python is "batteries-included", .NET is definitely "batteries-included", and as far as I have seen, Android API also has a lot of classes to design and implement *application/domain logic*, not directly related to visual presentation.

The main reason I am asking is because I don't know C++ and don't plan to learn it deeply (too much time needed), so if I had to take third party C++ libraries all the time and struggle to use them inside Qt projects that would be a strong point against going ahead.

The intended use is mostly to create small desktop apps for personal use while gaining insight on software design good practices - a profession I am slowly migrating to.

I have already used some Python/Pygtk (without IDE) and WPF (in VStudio/ExpressionBlend). In both platforms, most of my work is related to scientific computations, image processing and interactive scientific visualization, and there are good libraries for that either in Python (Numpy, Scipy, Matplotlib, Pandas, PIL, cairo) and .NET(AForge, alglib, System.Media.Media3D). I wonder if the Qt ecosystem is so complete in that regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt isn't a language in itself, so you can't compare it to Python or .NET. With that being said, Qt does provide general-purpose classes like containers, a Unicode string class, character set encoders/decoders, multimedia, device and file I/O, etc. All these modules are [fully documented](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/qtmodules.html).

There are also some external modules available for Qt, like [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net) which provides widgets for technical applications.

For other functionality where something Qt-specific isn't available, you can obviously use another appropriate library. Like OpenCV.

Oh, and you can use Qt in Python too, through [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro).

Comment: Excellent answer and links! One last little question, though: are PyQt applications COMPILED C++ (and thus run at C++ speed) or INTERPRETED PYTHON (and thus run at Py speed)?

Comment: @heltonbiker They're just regular Python, as any other Python application. Of course the Qt libraries themselves are still the same as without Python; they're C++ libraries and therefore compiled from their C++ sources. PyQt just provides bindings into those libraries. It's similar to PyGTK.

Comment: .NET isn't a language as well, it is a framework, it can be used with C#, C++ and maybe even more languages. .NET is very close to Qt, with the minor difference it is nor portable and the APIs aren't as nice.

Comment: .NET isn't a language. Like Qt, it's a toolkit (collection of useful classes that have been tried and tested). It has bindings for C#, C++, J#, Pascal (aka Delphi), ASP

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Qt doesn't have image processing libraries.  For that, you'll need to use something like OpenCV.   Qt does have libraries for loading most common image types.

However, Qt does extend beyond just GUI classes.

There is a *database module* that's quite convenient.  The *concurrency/threading* classes are nice.  I've enjoyed making use of the Qt *Networking* classes.  The *FileIO* classes are alright.

These classes/modules are all useful for making platform-independent code.  Things like image processing are mostly algorithmic and tend to be platform-independent by nature.  So I think they fall out of the scope of the Qt framework.  It shouldn't be too difficult, however, to simply find a library that does what you need and link that in to your project.

Comment: Yeah, that process of integrting external C++ libraries (like http://www.cgal.org for example) scares me a bit, but if things are kept in anything but the lowest level, I think that can be managed... Thanks for now!

Comment: Qt can do some image processing quite well, such as matrix transformations and composing multiple images together.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of the Qt Core services that heltonbiker and Nikos C. mentioned, can be thought of as extensions to C++, a little like std.  Although I often prefer the Qt implementations myself.  But Qt has gone much further with their libraries, with the I/O, and web services etc...

- The **QtXML** library provides reading and writing of XML files.  Traditionally we had always used xerces, but the Qt XML library is almost as simple as .NETs.
- The **QtNetwork** library offers TCP/IP and other networks services
- The **QtMultimedia** library performs playback and recording of audio
  and video content to the use of available devices like cameras and
  radios.
- The **QtSQL** library interfaces with SQL databases.

  And there is much more than that.  Although these are probably services that are used to most.  The other benefit is that for the most part the implementations are cross platform.  So for example using the I/O services does not require you to write separate code for Linux and Windows.  That is a general rule, and there are exceptions.  But I am sure most people would agree that any of the services they offer are easy to use, and well documented.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Qt provides ample abstraction besides UI - it comes with a set of functionality enhancing features that come with certain usage paradigms.

- Container classes - shallow copy by value, copy on write
- Implicit sharing for containers and certain data types
- Event driven, signals and slots
- A powerful and usable metasystem
- Properties
- Platform abstraction for a lot of functionality, from file access to network and multithreading
- Cross platform atomics (not that important since C++11 atomics)
- Settings API
- Undo API
- OpenGL abstraction (not necessarily UI, custom graphics)
- Basic image formats and basic image manipulations
- Qt Declarative, a.k.a QtQuick and QML markup (usable for all kind of structure markup BTW)
- Dynamic plugin API
- Platform abstraction and portability - same code, multiple platforms
- High and low level multimedia - audio, video
- Sensors and serial port
- Unit test
- XML, JSON, SQL
- An outdated and hopefully soon updated OpenCL abstraction
- Last but not least, a lot of 3rd party modules built around Qt fitting a wide range of applications

Honestly, all its missing is support for some more popular formats for file, media encoding/decoding and containers, some parallel and vector abstraction, USB, WIFI/NFC (in the works in an addon module) and it will be 100% versatile.

Note that you can also use Python with Qt, although I have no experience with that, Qt is a very versatile tool that allows for quick and easy application development - and since 5.1 supports pretty much the entire market, with the addition of Android and iOS to the list of supported platforms. It is very useful for creating custom use applications for creative or research purposes.

Although not perfect for every task, Qt is easily the "best of the bunch" of tools you can use in this regard. Unbeatable in terms of portability and very thorough, if not a little bloated for the set of functionality it provides. And finally, it is free, you can even develop commercial applications under LGPL as long as you link dynamically. All in all, it is well worth the investment to learn, the only downside is it lacks uniformity between the old C++ native APIs and the QML runtime, which is actively worked on and is based on JS, so the APIs are a bit different and some glue APIs are required to fuse C++ with JS and QML.

Answer (score 1):

(just for the record, from the [official site](http://qt.digia.com/Product/Qt-Core-Features--Functions/Library/)):

> **The Foundation: Qt Core Module**
>
> The Qt Core module forms the foundation of all Qt-based applications
>   with core non-graphical classes used by other modules.
>
> **Key Functions**
>
> - File IO, event and object handling
> - Multi-threading and concurrency
> - Plugins, setting management
> - Signals and Slots inter-object communications mechanism
>
> **Benefits**
>
> - Reduce development time and cost by leveraging a complete set of application building blocks
> - Develop portable code from the ground up with cross-platform functionality